In psycopg 3.x , is it possible to disable the Extended Query Protocol?
I'm connecting to pgbouncer via psycopg==3.1.19 and trying to perform a SHOW STATS (which pgbouncer itself will answer, it's not sent to postgresql)
I'm getting a ProtocolViolation: extended query protocol not supported by admin console from pgbouncer itself.
This is the code that I use
import psycopg
from psycopg.rows import dict_row

conn = psycopg.connect("host=127.0.0.1 port=6432 user=myuser password=mypass dbname=pgbouncer ", row_factory=dict_row, autocommit=False)
conn.prepare_threshold = None
conn.prepared_max = 0

cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("SHOW STATS") # ProtocolViolation: extended query protocol not supported by admin console


I had a look at psycopg 3 documentation, and the connect() does not seem to have anything about "extended query protocol".
So it's there any way to disable this extended query protocol in psycopg 3 or my only option is to downgrade to psycopg 2?

if you mean setting conn.prepare_threshold = None and conn.prepared_max = 0 , yes, I just tried, it doesn't work. SHOW STATS is not a prepared statement so I guess none of those really apply.

You might try Client Cursors. From the docs: Using ClientCursor, Psycopg 3 behaviour will be more similar to psycopg2 .... Not sure if that means it does not use extended query protocol as I don't have a way to text against pgbouncer. Still it might be worth a try.

From source see here client_cursor.py lines ~65-76. Indicates that ClientCursor uses simple protocol unless forced into pipeline or extended protocol.

I tried with cur = psycopg.ClientCursor(conn) and same problem.

You can use the ClientCursor in autocommit mode, see https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg/discussions/808.
We would like to include this information in the documentation (https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg/issues/819). A MR in that direction is welcome.
Note: we are also testing to check if the need to use autocommit mode can be relaxed: see https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg/issues/820.

As mentioned in the OP downgrading to psycopg2 will allow to perform SHOW STATS towards pgbouncer (using pgbouncer database):
pip install psycopg2

import psycopg2
import psycopg2.extras

conn = psycopg2.connect("host=127.0.0.1 port=6432 user=myuser password=mypass dbname=pgbouncer ") # SHOW STATS only available if you connect to the special database called "pgbouncer"
conn.set_session(autocommit=True) # BEGIN not supported for database "pgbouncer" 

cur = conn.cursor(cursor_factory=psycopg2.extras.RealDictCursor) # to get column names
cur.execute("SHOW STATS")
print(cur.fetchone())

That will print the stats record:
RealDictRow([('database', 'pgbouncer'),
             ('total_xact_count', Decimal('4')),
             ('total_query_count', Decimal('4')),
             ('total_received', Decimal('0')),
             ('total_sent', Decimal('0')),
             ('total_xact_time', Decimal('0')),
             ('total_query_time', Decimal('0')),
             ('total_wait_time', Decimal('0')),
             ('avg_xact_count', Decimal('0')),
             ('avg_query_count', Decimal('0')),
             ('avg_recv', Decimal('0')),
             ('avg_sent', Decimal('0')),
             ('avg_xact_time', Decimal('0')),
             ('avg_query_time', Decimal('0')),
             ('avg_wait_time', Decimal('0'))])

But still that is not really disabling extended query support in psycopg3, it's just using psycopg2 instead.

As indicated by @piro and Adrian Klaver.  Both ClientCursor and auto-commit mode are required to disable extended query protocol and use simple query protocol instead.
import psycopg

conn = psycopg.connect("host=127.0.0.1 port=6432 user=myuser password=mypass dbname=pgbouncer", 
  row_factory=dict_row, 
  autocommit=True,  #  both autocommit and ClientCursor are needed for simple query protocol
  cursor_factory=psycopg.ClientCursor, #  both autocommit and ClientCursor are needed for simple query protocol
  )
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("SHOW STATS") # no longer raises a ProtocolViolation error
print(cur.fetchall())
cur.close()
conn.close()


